# SQL Server Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have this query to fill in a date in a table that's giving me this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Below are my table declaration and query. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE #inv
(
      Rep_LName NVARCHAR(50)
    , Rep_FName NVARCHAR(50)
    , Rep_ID NVARCHAR(50)
    , Rep_Email NVARCHAR(100)
    , Rep_Status NVARCHAR(50)
    , Rep_BU NVARCHAR(50)
    , Sales_Force NVARCHAR(50)
    , Territory NVARCHAR(50)
    , Sample_Eligibility NVARCHAR(50)
    , DM_Name NVARCHAR(100)
    , Phys_Inv_Date DATETIME
    , Last_Reconciled DATETIME
    , Inv_Type NVARCHAR(50)
    , Days_Since_Last_inv INT
)
```

I'm trying to fill the `Phys_Inv_Date` field inside a cursor like so:

```
OPEN Inventory_info

FETCH NEXT FROM Inventory_info INTO @rep_ID, @call_date

WHILE ( @@fetch_status = 0 ) BEGIN  

        SELECT
            @ls_Sql = 'update #inv set Phys_Inv_Date = case when inventory_type = ''physical'' then '
            + @call_date
            + ' else b.inv_date end from #inv a INNER JOIN (select top 1 call_date, rep_id from inv_header where call_date < '
            + @call_date + ' and rep_id = ''' + @rep_id
            + ''') b ON a.rep_id = b.rep_id WHERE Phys_Inv_Date IS NULL'

        EXEC (@ls_Sql)

        FETCH NEXT FROM Inventory_info INTO @rep_ID, @call_date

END

CLOSE Inventory_info
DEALLOCATE Inventory_info
```

Comment: What is the 'character string' you are trying to convert to a date?  In other words, what is the value of @call_date?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here? It looks like you can use regular SQL with parameters, then you won't have to worry about formatting `datetime` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using SQL with parameters? There's no obvious reason why you need dynamic SQL here, and assuming that the variables are the correct data types then you won't need to convert anything:

```
update 
    #inv 
set 
    Phys_Inv_Date = case 
        when inventory_type = 'physical' then @call_date
        else b.inv_date end
 from 
    #inv a 
    INNER JOIN (
        select top 1 
            call_date, 
            rep_id 
        from 
            inv_header where call_date < @call_date
            and rep_id = @rep_id
    ) b
    ON a.rep_id = b.rep_id 
WHERE 
    Phys_Inv_Date IS NULL
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `call_date` in `inventory_info` is a datetime column, you need to [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it to a string

```
select @ls_Sql='
  update #inv set Phys_Inv_Date = case when inventory_type = ''physical''
                                  then ''' + CONVERT(varchar,@call_date,112) + '''
                                  else b.inv_date end
  from #inv a
  JOIN (select top 1 call_date, rep_id
        from inv_header
        where call_date < ''' + CONVERT(varchar,@call_date,112) + '''
        and rep_id = ''' + rtrim(@rep_id) + ''') b
    ON a.rep_id = b.rep_id
  WHERE Phys_Inv_Date IS NULL';
```

That gives you a string of the format YYYYMMDD, but you still need to enclose it in quotes, much the same as you've done with @rep_id.  However, I'm guessing that @rep_id is actually an *int*, so you can use RTRIM to cast it to a varchar.

Note also that ***multi-line strings*** are allowed in SQL Server and make your code a lot more readable.